# How to display imgur gifs in webview?

Tags: android, webview, gif

I have a simple app that has a list of images/gifs and when the user clicks it shows the full image inside a webview.
My webview activity is really simple, it just takes the url of the gif and pass it to the webview:

```
public class ItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item);
        String data = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("url");
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.item_view);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl(data);

    }

}
```

The problem is that the gifs are never loaded, when i click on it the webview opens and i can see an image of the gif with the imgur loading spiral on the corner and the play button on the bottom, but it just stays that way and the gif never loads.

Comment: Yes, here is one example: http://i.imgur.com/GmTR0nS.gifv

Comment: i removed the v, same problem.

Comment: Yes i am,stackoverflow just reformats it for some reason, the entire url i am passing is exaclty what you described

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little late but my maybe try removing the .gif or .gifv ending.